# How to configure RRAS to route all traffic through squid proxy?

Tags: vpn, proxy, squid, pptp, rras

I have a VPN server up and running on a windows server 2003. All the users are able to connect to the server and NAT their IP (use server IP and internet).
but my problem is government filtering on my windows server and i need a tunnel for my server
to route all vpn users traffic who connect with pptp and l2tp protocol to my server to squid proxy.
I have a proxy server address and port configured.

my question is How to configure RRAS to route all traffic through this proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't configure RRAS to do it, you'd configure a proxy explicitly for the client as part of the Connection Manager Admin Kit, or VPN connectoid.

I think another approach might involve providing a WPAD hostname to those clients, but I think you're asking if it can be done transparently when RRAS sees port 80 traffic, in which case, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with port forwarding ([netsh interface portproxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_1)).

For example:

```
netsh
netsh > interface portproxy
netsh interface portproxy > add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectaddress=<proxy_IP> connectport=8080
```

Perhaps check out [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/501433/windows-rras-for-port-forwarding) answer and adapt it?

Note, you will need to install IPv6 support for this to work, even if you aren't using IPv6.

-- ab1